# How to assign a jQuery Validation rule when I can't edit the class of my input?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm trying to understand how I can specify an inline validation rule, such as "required," for a parent element of the input element. So for example, currently the plugin will validate the name field if it has a "required" class:

```
<input name="email" class="required">
```

But my code only allows me to add that into the parent element

```
<li class="required">
   <input name="email">
```

Is there a way to make validate look for the required class of the parent element instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$("li.required input").rules("add", {
    required: true
});
```